# Criar 2 lista a partir de outra sem repetição

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista com 18 jogadores, e agora pretendo desses 18 jogadores fazer mais duas listas, uma equipa suplente com 7 e outra equipa titular com 11, tudo aleatoriamente, ou seja os elementos para as duas novas listas não se podem repetir, pois vou necessitar de fazer substituições.
Desta maneira os elementos repetem-se:

```
ListGr=[]
convGr=random.sample(Gr,2)
ListGr.append([convGr])
  
ListDef=[]
convDef=random.sample(Def,5)
ListDef.append([convDef])

ListMed=[]
convMed=random.sample(Med,5)
ListMed.append([convMed])

ListAvanc=[]
convAvanc=random.sample(Avan,6)
ListAvanc.append([convAvanc])

print()
           
print("Lista de Convocados, 1º jogo: ")

print("Guarda Redes", convGr)
print("Defesas", convDef)
print("Médios", convMed)
print("Avançados", convAvanc)

print()

Sgr = random.sample(convGr,1)
Sdef = random.sample(convDef,2)
Smed = random.sample(convMed,2)
Savanc = random.sample(convAvanc,2)

ListaSuplentes=[]

ListaSuplentes.append(Sgr)
ListaSuplentes.append(Sdef)
ListaSuplentes.append(Smed)
ListaSuplentes.append(Savanc)

Gr = random.sample(convGr,1)
Def = random.sample(convDef,4)
Med = random.sample(convMed,3)
Avan = random.sample(convAvanc,3)

Lista11=[]

Lista11.append(Gr)
Lista11.append(Def)
Lista11.append(Med)
Lista11.append(Avan) 
        
print()

print("Equipa Suplente",ListaSuplentes)

print()

print("Equipa Titular: ",Lista11)
```

Comment: Se entendi bem, é mais simples embaralhar a lista com `randpm.shuffle`, e depois pegue os 7 primeiros e os 11 restantes

Answer (score -2):

O que eu faria é: criar uma copia da minha lista de jogadores, nessa lista seleciona-los aleatoriamente pelo índice dessa lista nova e logo após usar o comando: `lista.pop[indice]` que retiraria o elemento da lista nova, para que não houvessem repetições.
Pode-se também criar uma lista de jogadores que já foram selecionados, e ai verificar se um já foi selecionado, se sim eu sortearia outro aleatório.